# Index Error: list index out of range (Python), numbering correct

Tags: python, index-error

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times before, however I have double checked the numbering and the error is still appearing. I was wondering whether there was anything else obvious I have missed.

```
with open('imagefile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    imagelog = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in imagelog:
        if row[0] == 'IMG' and row[2].endswith('.RAW'):
            gpsAndAtt.append({ 'label': 'IMG', 'timeMS': float(row[1]), 'file': row[2]})
```

The error comes at the 4th line of the above code. However the .csv file as below, 3 columns. Or according to Python, 0,1,2

> IMG,330985,033.RAW
>   IMG,332985,034.JPG
>   IMG,343985,035.RAW

The code is designed to strip out elements of the .csv for use with another file.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

sorted empty lines issue in original question (poor formatting on stack)

Comment: Can you make your script print `row` immediately after you call it in the `for` loop? Then you can see *exactly* what `row` looks like.

Comment: I think you may have some empty lines in your csv file.

Comment: @JackParkinson print row returns ['{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf830']
['{\\fonttbl\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 Helvetica;}']
['{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}']
['{\\*\\expandedcolortbl;;}']
['\\paperw11900\\paperh16840\\margl1440\\margr1440\\vieww10800\\viewh8400\\viewkind0']
['\\pard\\tx566\\tx1133\\tx1700\\tx2267\\tx2834\\tx3401\\tx3968\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural\\partightenfactor0']
[]

Comment: @JackParkinson then followed by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Walker/Desktop/Important/SArONG Glitter Project/Code/Python/NetCDF/TextWranglerRunTemp-GetAttributesFromDroneLog.py", line 32, in <module>
    if row[0] == 'IMG' and row[2].endswith('.RAW'): 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: None of those lists have any commas so it looks like they have at most one element, not three. And I don't see "IMG,330985,033.RAW" anywhere. Are you sure you're reading from the right file?

Comment: That output isn't what you expect to see, is it? Surely you're expecting to see the lines you quoted? So something must be going wrong in the way you are reading your data to begin with.

Comment: @Kevin definitely the correct file, the full file only has about 15 lines

Comment: @JackParkinson agree! CSV opened as text fine, however when opened in excel, the top print row appeared... so fault my end somewhere, thanks for your help troubleshooting! seems to have produced the correct output file now

Answer (score 0):

Not **the** "answer", since on the face of it, there should be no error, *but* where you have potentially erroneous input, you ought to have a "guard" on your returned 'row', since you are accessing row[2].
(By all means flag/display the offending row, for diagnostic purposes !)

Hence:

```
for row in imagelog:
  if len(row) >= 2:
      ...
```